# Can´t start Kibana because the superuser "elastic" can´t write indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I installed elasticsearch and Kibana on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I just want to try Kibana on my PC, but I activated security as I want to install Elastic Agent.

The problem is that when I start Kibana I get:

> waitForDeleteByQueryTask task failed with the following error:
>
> \n{"type":"security_exception","reason":"action
> [indices:data/write/delete/byquery] is unauthorized for user [elastic]
> with effective roles [superuser] on restricted indices
> [.kibana_alerting_cases_8.12.0_001], this action is granted by the
> index privileges [delete,write,all]"}

Then I get similar errors refered to many other indexes:

- .kibana_8.12.0_001
- .kibana_ingest_8.12.0_001
- .kibana_security_solution_8.12.0_001
- etc.

On kibana.yml I have:

```yaml
server.host: localhost

elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://elastic:<password>@localhost:9200"]

elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
elasticsearch.password: "<password>"

elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/etc/kibana/elasticsearch-ca.pem" ]

pid.file: /run/kibana/kibana.pid

xpack.fleet.registryProxyUrl: <proxy>

xpack.security.encryptionKey: <key>
xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey: <key>
xpack.reporting.encryptionKey: <key>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: which user are you using in kibana.yml ?

Comment: In the logs you shared it says `unauthorized for user [elastic]` in the kibana.yml it looks like you are using `elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"` user. There is a dilemma in here. Please check you shared the correct kibana.yml. If you made any changes on `kibana.yml` restart the kibana and check the logs again.

Comment: It is the correct kibana.yml. I agree that it's weird discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks for approve that. I recommend you to run the kibana on console to debug it.`./bin/kibana --allow-root`.

Answer (score 0):

> s unauthorized for user [elastic] with effective roles [superuser] on restricted indices [.kibana_alerting_cases_8.12.0_001],

This part says your [built-in user](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-roles.html) elastic can not operate on system index of kibana_alerting_cases. The system indices starts with a dot.

Normally roles are created under **Stack Management** then **roles** on Kibana.
Roles can be assigned to the users (also under **Stack Management** but under **Users**).

Please check if the user is allowed to work on this index.